# PYTHON APSCHEDULER: missed job event not triggered by the listener

Tags: python, listener, apscheduler

I need to trigger a missed job event using a listener in APSCHEDULER.

My very first, but not working properly, code is the following:
`

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.events import *
import asyncio
import time

def listener(ev):
    print(f"MISSED JOB: {ev}")

def dataread():
    print("TEST")
    time.sleep(2)

c = BackgroundScheduler()

c.add_listener(listener, EVENT_JOB_MISSED)
c.add_job(dataread, trigger="interval", seconds=1)
c.start()

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    pass
```

`

could someone help me please discovering how to set the code in the proper way to let it operates as expected?

thanks

Comment: Works fine here:
```
TEST
Execution of job "dataread (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2023-06-17 23:27:23 EEST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
```

Comment: Also why are you running a threaded scheduler along with the asyncio event loop?

Comment: it does not work for me...

Comment: Can you perhaps be a tad more specific than "does not work"?

Comment: sure, this is the final resut: TEST
Execution of job "dataread (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2023-06-23 21:18:44 CEST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "dataread (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2023-06-23 21:18:45 CEST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
TEST
Execution of job "dataread (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2023-06-23 21:18:47 CEST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
Execution of job "dataread (trigger: interval[0:00:01] ...

Comment: it does not work because the listener function that prints out "MISSED JOB:" is never triggered even if the execution of the monitored job is skipped because it hadn't finished the execution...

Comment: The script you posted works fine for me. It prints both the MISSED JOB and TEST messages, as expected.

Comment: which version are you using?